# Google Sheets query cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to have my query reference a cell, but I keep getting errors:

`=query(Sheet1!A3:X2838,"Select I, H, Q, P, J, N, O, S Where (N>10) and (J>"""&K2&""") Order By Q Desc Limit 80")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
J>"""&K2&"""
```

by

```
J>"&K2&"
```

The above because QUERY doesn't require a delimiter for numbers

---

The spreadsheet doesn't include the formula referred in the question.

It contains `=query(Sheet1!A3:X2838,B2)` where the content of B2 is not a formula.

Replace the content of B2 by

```
="Select I, H, Q, P, J, N, O, S Where (N>10) and (J>"&K2&") Order By Q Desc Limit 80"
```

Comment: Your spreadsheet is not using the formula included in the question, if you will use B2 as the second argument of QUERY, you should make it's content a formula

Comment: I works now thanks so much! but if I wanted to use B2 , how would i make B2's content a formula?

Comment: See the most recent edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks, youre the best!